# Special characters/kanji problems using Python unicode

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters, moviepy

I want to use videofileclip(), but a UnicodeDecodeError occurs.
The videofiles include japanese kanji or special characters.

My example code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys  
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

a='H:\\kittens.mkv'
clip1=VideoFileClip(a)

b='H:\\“ēī①”.mp4'
clip2=VideoFileClip(b)

if clip1.fps >= clip2.fps:
    os.remove(b)
else:
    os.remove(a)
```

'a' works fine:

```
>>> a='H:\\kittens.mkv'
>>> clip=VideoFileClip(a)
>>>
```

but 'b' doesn't work:

```
>>> b='H:\\“ēī①”.mp4'
>>> clip=VideoFileClip(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 5
5, in __init__
    reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 3
2, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 2
70, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    filename, infos))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 54: invalid
start byte
>>> b
'H:\\\xa1\xb0??\xa8\xe7\xa1\xb1.mp4'
>>> print b
H:\“??①”.mp4
>>> print b.decode('cp949')
H:\“??①”.mp4
>>>
```

I've tried this, but it also doesn't work.

```
b=b.decode('cp949')
b=b.decode('cp949').encode('utf-8')
b=unicode(b.decode('cp949'))
```

I think that Windows 7 supports Unicode file names (in Japanese kanji or special characters), but the character set of Python (2.x) (cp949) does not support special characters. What can I do for this problem?

Comment: I suspect it is not your code that does not support unicode, but the module `moviepy`. I remember there is a trick to avoid this, I'll try to find it.

Comment: thanks. I waiting for your help.

Comment: It may not be this specific problem, but [why sys.setdefaultencoding will break code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).  It's never needed and there is a reason it can't be called without the `reload(sys)` trick.  Remove it.  Also try a Unicode string instead of a byte string for the filename, e.g. `u'H:\\“ēī①”.mp4'`.  Make sure you save the source file in your declared source encoding of UTF-8. `b` is currently a byte string encoded in UTF-8, which is an unlikely filename in Windows.

Comment: +1 what Mark said. To access non-ASCII filenames in Windows you will need to use Unicode strings. This tells Python to use Windows-specific code to call the Win32 file API instead of using the standard C byte-based APIs which under Microsoft's implementation are limited to the locale-specific (‘ANSI’) code page (probably 1252; definitely not 949). Setting the default encoding will not affect file access, and is a terrible idea (why won't this die?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround using the [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32) extensions.
Basically, you use the [`GetShortPathName`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetShortPathName_meth.html) function to generate a legacy [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) from a unicode path.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import win32api
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip


def short_path(unicode_path):
    return win32api.GetShortPathName(unicode_path)


v1 = '“ēī①”.mp4'
print os.path.isfile(v1)  # False

v2 = u'“ēī①”.mp4'
print os.path.isfile(v2)  # True

# clip = VideoFileClip(v1)  # IOError
# clip = VideoFileClip(v2)  # UnicodeEncodeError
clip = VideoFileClip(short_path(v2))  # OK
print clip.duration
```